# Why does using a recyclerview in a fragment cause a NPE on class inflation?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development and was trying to make a contact list inside a fragment.  However, running the app generates the error: "Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in com.example.wildfire:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference"  Here is the code:
**HomeFragment.java:**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public HomeFragment() {}
    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);View root = binding.getRoot();
        return binding.getRoot();
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        RecyclerView rview = view.findViewById(R.id.contactsviewer);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutmgr = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new MessageView_Adapter(contact.getalist(10));
        rview.setLayoutManager(layoutmgr);
        rview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.navigation_msgs, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_fpit).build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);
    }
}
```

and **fragment_home.xml:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.messages.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/contactsviewer"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Yes, I have looked at the the other related posts on here, but none of those solutions have worked.  Please help.

Comment: Why are you using `findViewById` if you are already using `ViewBinding`?

Comment: I dont know what view bindings do.  it was autogenerated by android studio.